# Javascript Countdown Timer - Client Time vs mySQL Time

Tags: javascript, mysql

The following code is a countdown timer. It pulls an ending datetime stamp from mySQL and uses it to count to. The issue is that the mysql time may be in a different time zone than the client who is looking at the page with the timer.

I also pull the current timestamp from mySQL with NOW(), thinking that this would allow the timer to count as the user who created it intended.

if I put the NOW() value in this snippet

```
var timeDiff = target - (new Date());
```

like so

```
var nt='2015-03-11 05:12:15'.split(/[- :]/);
var timeDiff = target - (new Date(nt[0],nt[1]-1,nt[2],nt[3],nt[4],nt[5]));
```

the counter shows the correct time left when the page loads but does not count interactively any longer. I think I need to get the difference in hours between the clients local time and the mySQL NOW() and adjust the date in this line to get the interactive timer to run.

```
var timeDiff = target - (new Date());
```

nothing I try seems to work.

This is the working script if the client happens to be int he same time zone.

```
 <script language="javaScript">              
  document.write(hrs);
  function timeDiff(target) {
    function z(n) {return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
    var timeDiff = target - (new Date()); 
    var hours    = timeDiff / 3.6e6 | 0;
    var minutes  = timeDiff % 3.6e6 / 6e4 | 0;
    var seconds  = timeDiff % 6e4 / 1e3 | 0;
    if (hours<0 || minutes<0 || seconds<0) {
      document.getElementById('divBody').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('divExpired').style.display='';    
      return '<b>EXPIRED</b>';
      }
    else {
      return '<b>' + z(hours) + '</b> Hours, <b>' + z(minutes) + '</b>  Mins, <b>' + z(seconds) + '</b> Secs';
      }
    }
  function doCountDown(target) {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '<img src=\"/backhaul/images/my/al-active.png\" class=\"vm2\" /> <span style=\"color:#c40000\"><b>EXPIRES IN</b></span>: ' + timeDiff(target);
    var lag = 1020 - (new Date() % 100);
    setTimeout(function(){doCountDown(target);}, lag);
    }
  window.onload = function() {
    //Insert Expiratin Date from mySQL into t var
    var t='2015-03-12 00:00:00'.split(/[- :]/);
    doCountDown(new Date(t[0],t[1]-1,t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5]));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please wait for better comments / answers, as I don't have the necessary knowledge. Anyway, if you have to work with timezones, it is better to work with [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetimes from SQL (MySQL has date conversion functions); Javascript could support that format, but in case it doesn't, you can use a [javascript library (Google search)](https://www.google.it/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+date+library)

Comment: So convert it to UTC....

Comment: `setInterval()` with an AJAX call inside of it may be the way to go for this, then you won't have to deal with Client vs. Server time. The Client time is usually dependent on their computer, which of course they can alter.

Comment: setInterval is a poor choice for keeping time because the queued events can drift quite a bit, especially if the thread gets busy, a confim() message for example. it would be more reliable to use client time or precision.now() to avoid client-clock adjustments. at any rate, you don't need php, just grab the Date header from any ajax request, subtract the client date, and you're left with the C/S offset in ms.

Comment: The correct localtime would be a nicety but really I just need to make sure 2 hours set in central time translates to 2 hours eastern. The countdown should be simply 2 hours relative to the mySQL time.

Comment: Follow @epascarello's advice. Once you have the UTC timestamp available in javascript you can adjust it to user's time zone using it's specific offset: `var date = new Date(); var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();`

Comment: I think you may find [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) very handy for multiple aspects of your code. It's a great JS library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and displaying dates with JavaScript.

Comment: Make a server call on body load to fetch current server time and then initialize your local time with server. Once you do it you clock client side clock will sync with server time then you can do whatever you want to do..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, but I'll elaborate on two ways.

### Method 1 : Adjust the time on the client side

One way is what you are trying to do which is to get the current time of the server and find the difference with the client's current time. You can simply adjust the server target time to the client's time. This can be done with

```
var serverDifference=Date.parse(mysql_data.now)-Date.now()
var target=Date.parse(mysql_data.server_time_in_two_hours)-serverDifference
```

Then you can input it into your function without problem.

### Method 2: Calculate the times remaining, server side

Since you just need a countdown timer, I think it's more appropriate to simply send the seconds left server side. This can be done with SQL using

```
 select timestampdiff(SECOND,now(),end_time) seconds_left from timers;
```

Then you simply just make a timer that counts down based on the number of seconds left instead of a target date. You can calculate the number of seconds left by deducting the time that the javascript has run from the time received from the server. So something like

```
var client_start=Date.now()
function timeDiff_fromseconds(target) {
    function z(n) {return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
    var timeDiff =target-(Date.now()-client_start)
    var hours    = timeDiff / 3.6e6 | 0;
    var minutes  = timeDiff % 3.6e6 / 6e4 | 0;
    var seconds  = timeDiff % 6e4 / 1e3 | 0;
    if (hours<0 || minutes<0 || seconds<0) {   
      return '<b>EXPIRED</b>';
      }
    else {
      return '<b>' + z(hours) + '</b> Hours, <b>' + z(minutes) + '</b>  Mins, <b>' + z(seconds) + '</b> Secs';
      }
}
```

There is also [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) as suggested by [@dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis). This returns the number of milliseconds since the tab opened and is accurate to 1/1000th of a millisecond. And this doesn't change even if the system clock of the client browser changes. For full support, you should use a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5438650) ([As of the time of this writing, iOS Safari doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=performance.now)). In this context we can replace `Date.now()` with it.

### JSFiddle Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/3o3u5r5j/1/

Comment: i don't think your drawbacks for #1 are needed. even if the clocks are radically off, both still advance 1 per second, and lag is rarely over 1000ms. there's nothing that says you can't simply calc the # of seconds needed from the first code and then feed that to your 2nd code.

Comment: @dandavis Yeah, thinking about it again, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that performance.now() is more precise and ignores local clock adjustments made after the tab is opened.

Comment: @dandavis Actually the time difference could be massive.  I always use a version of Method 2 because you have no idea how badly a users clock could be set.  But you can guruntee that 23 seconds ago is the same amount of time on both server and client.

Method 2 is the way you should go :)

Comment: @MarshallOfSound: interestingly, it doesn't actually matter how far off the client's clock is unless you're showing a clock (and even then arithmetic can adjust). in this case, it's a more-or-less a countdown timer, and the only info you need from the server is the # of seconds in the future from the time of the request. as i mentioned, performance.now() is not tied to the clock, so it can't matter what the client's clock is set to.

Comment: That's basically what I said.  You should never send a time back, rather a number of seconds relative to now. @dandavis

Comment: @MarshallOfSound: think of it this way: the server's time is 00:01:30, and it wants to start something at 00:02:10 (40 seconds in the future). the client converts 00:01:30 (the run time) and 00:02:10 (the Date HTTP header) to epoc, then subtracts the former from the later, leaving 40,000ms. the client then subtracts the current  perfomance.now() (lets call it 3500 by the time the script runs) from that 40,000 to arrive at a figure of 36,500 ms until the server event; the exact right amount of time. the client clock is never used.

Comment: @dandavis So you are saying that you should send the current time and the target time back from the server, then make the client calculate the difference...  Why not just send the difference in the first place like I was sayin??? o_0

Comment: @MarshallOfSound: math can be done on either side, but doing it client-side is the only way without server-side scripting; using a static end date, ex: from a CMS post, and an apache-provided Date HTTP header. since there was no PHP tag, i wanted to cover all the bases.

Comment: @dandavis Fair enough on the lack of server side language tag.  But the basic concept of having to calculate a relative time difference (somehow either client or server side) is the way to go? (I think we agreed on that) :P

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to get remaining amount of seconds from database  instead of expiry time (meaning to calculate it at the server and send to the client). Then you can use following code (sample). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vda06xw/)

```
var countDownId;
var timer;
function countDown(){
    console.log(timer--);
    if(timer<=0){
        clearInterval(countDownId);
        alert('time expired');
    }
}

function startCountDown(secondsToExpire){
    var milliseconds = 1 * 1000 ;// 1 second
    timer = secondsToExpire;

    countDownId = setInterval(function() { countDown();},milliseconds);
}

  window.onload = function() {
    //Insert remaining time from expiration
    var timeRemaining = 5;
    startCountDown(timeRemaining);
  }
```

You can tweak this to suit your needs.